# mysql index usage question

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a simple query that looks like

```
select id, name from mytable where age=28 order by name
```

the EXPLAIN output confuses me,  I got

```
possible_keys : age
key : name
```

Does that mean mysql finally decided to use the index 'name' to fetch all the rows? Is the age index used or not? How many indexes are used in this query? If it's the name index that mysql finnally chooses to use, what happened to the 'age' index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, name is used and age is not. Best solution is to have a combined key on both age and name (in that order). That way, queries can make use of this index when sorting and filtering on both columns.

Comment: Does that mean in the case that the indexes in where and order by clauses are different, mysql will always pick one and only one to use unless I made them a combined index?

Comment: I wouldn't say 'always', because I'm not sure. But usually this is the case. MySQL tends to use a single index, and tends to use the wrong one unless there is only *the one* perfect index. Sometimes MySQL merges two indexes on the fly, making it even slower.

Comment: If the 'age=28' aren't used, does that mean my query will probably be a full table scan, since there's no index to reduce the rows to be scanned coz name is just for sorting?

Comment: It seems so, although MySQL might decide otherwise when the number of record in the table grows. I assume it is relatively small now (less than a few thousand records)?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I know what to do next now. Appreciate it.